# reducing the output of the mongodb by taking latest documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Well, this is my collection

```js
{

"company" : "500010"

"eqtcorp" : {

    "306113" : {
        "DATE" : "2014-05-05 16:43:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "16:43"
     },
     "306118" : {
         "DATE" : "2014-05-08 16:43:00.000",
         "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
         "time" : "18:43"
     },
     "306114" : {
         "DATE" : "2014-06-02 16:43:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "20:43"
     }
     "306116" : {
         "DATE" : "2014-03-02 12:30:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "20:43"
     }
     "306115" : {
         "DATE" : "2014-08-02 04:45:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "20:43"
     }
     "306117" : {
         "DATE" : "2014-07-02 10:16:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "20:43"
     }                  

     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
           }

}
```

if I query like

```js
db.collection_name.find({"company": "500010"})
```

I will get the whole. Since there are many subdocuments under "eqtcorp", I need only 3 subdocuments with latest date. Simply need a reverse sort on the basis of the "DATE" field in every subdocuments under "eqtcorp" and take the first 3. It is realy a challenge since I am new with Mongodb and mapreduce.

What I am expecting as output is

```js
{

"company" : "500010"

"eqtcorp" : {        

    "306113" : {
        "DATE" : "2014-05-05 16:43:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "16:43"
     },
     "306118" : {
         "DATE" : "2014-05-08 16:43:00.000",
         "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
         "time" : "18:43"
     },

     "306116" : {
         "DATE" : "2014-03-02 12:30:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "20:43"
     }               

           }
}
```

Any shoot?

Comment: where does "CORP" : "NIFTY" come from in the result ? Am I missing something ? I don't find it in the original document.

Comment: since you don't want the entire embedded structure with the company you should not be storing it that way.  Store a document for each company/date combination, index it and then when you query for company you can sort by date descending, limit(3) to get three most recent ones.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things not really helping you here which essentially complicates what is an otherwise a simple operation.

You have dates that are actually strings which you really should change to be proper BSON date types. It will help you later where you will likely want it so you should change them. Fortunately they are at least lexically scoped by order of "YYYY-MM-DD" so they will sort, but just don't expect much other use out of them.

You also really should be using an array rather than nesting sub-documents by keys. These are really hard to query as you need to specify the exact path to the element. As such you are almost always restricted to JavaScript processing, which is much slower than the alternatives. I'll cover that later, but moving on:

You can approach this with mapReduce is as follows:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function () {
        for ( var k in this.eqtcorp ) {
            this.eqtcorp[k].key = k;
            emit( 1, this.eqtcorp[k] );
        }
    },
    function (key,values) {

        var reduced = {};

        values.sort(function(a,b) {
            return (( a.DATE > b.DATE ) ? -1 : (( a.DATE < b.DATE ) ? 1 : 0));
        }).slice(-3).forEach(function(doc) {
            reduced[doc.key] = doc;
        });

        return reduced;

    },
    { 
        "query": { "company": "50010" },
        "finalize": function(key,vaue) {
            for (var k in value) {
               delete value[k].key;
            }
            return value;
        },
        "out": { "inline": 1 },
    })
)
```

In the mapper I am currently using an emitted key as `1`. The reason for this is so the statement would work to "aggregate" all results across multiple documents. But if you really only wanted to do this per your "company" value then you can emit that as the key instead, as in:

```js
            emit( this.company, this.eqtcorp[k] );
```

Essentially the mapper is breaking apart each document to just output each sub-key of "eqtcorp" as it's own document. These are then passed on to the reducer.

The reducer, which can be invoked multiple times, takes it's input array of "values" for the same "key" and processes them first with a `sort` on that array. Once sorted (in ascending order) you then `slice` the last three items off the array and adds each of them to the reduced result.

As I say, the reducer can be invoked several times, so each pass does not necessarily get the "whole" list of values per grouping key. This is the essential part of the "reduce" phase in that it "incrementally" takes each input set and returns, eventually running the combination of results that have been reduced until there is only one "key" value that contains just the three results you want.

Then there is just the finalize function which cleans up some of the convenience housekeeping that was done to simplify the processing of the result by it's original sub-document keys. Other things are just the selection query and the choice of output, which depending on your needs may be to another collection. Or of course you can omit the selection query to process all documents.

---

As stated earlier the document structure does not help and would be better suited to arrays. So you should rather have a document like this:

```js
{

    "company" : "500010",

    "eqtcorp" : [

         { 
            "key": "306113" 
            "DATE" : "2014-05-05 16:43:00.000",
            "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
            "time" : "16:43"
         },
         {
            "key": "306118",
            "DATE" : "2014-05-08 16:43:00.000",
            "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
            "time" : "18:43"
         },
         {
            "key": "306114",
            "DATE" : "2014-06-02 16:43:00.000",
            "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
            "time" : "20:43"
         },
         {
            "key:"306116",
            "DATE" : "2014-03-02 12:30:00.000",
            "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
            "time" : "20:43"
         },
         { 
             "key": "306115",
             "DATE" : "2014-08-02 04:45:00.000",
             "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
             "time" : "20:43"
         },
         {
             "key": "306117",
             "DATE" : "2014-07-02 10:16:00.000",
             "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
            "time" : "20:43"
         }                  
     ]
}
```

Though leaving the date formats alone for now, this makes things much cleaner as you can simplify processing and indeed use things like the aggregation framework for much faster processing if you were intending to say "find the top three values" across the entire collection. This would be as simple as:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$eqtcorp" },

    // Sort the results by the dates
    { "$sort": "eqtcorp.DATE" -1 },

    // Limit the top three results
    { "$limit": 3 },

    // Optionally group back as an array
    { "$group": {
        "_id": null,
        "eqtcorp": { "$push": "$eqtcorp" }
    }}

])
```

That would be for the whole collection, getting the top three per company value is not impossible but a bit more involved as there is no equivalent of slice

```js
db.collection.aggregate([

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$eqtcorp" },

    // Sort the results by company and date
    { "$sort": "company": 1, "eqtcorp.DATE" -1 },

    // Group back keeping the top value
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$company",
        "all": { "$push": "$eqtcorp" },
        "one": { "$first": "$eqtcorp" }
    }},

    // Unwind again
    { "$unwind": "$all" },

    // match the "seen" value
    { "$project": {
        "all": 1,
        "one": 1,
        "seen": {
            "$eq": [ "$all", "$one" ]
        } 
    }},

    // Filter out "seen"
    { "$match": { "seen": false } },

    // Group back keeping the new top
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "all": { "$push": "$all },
        "one": { "$first": "$one" },
        "two": { "$first": "$all }
    }},

    // Unwind again
    { "$unwind": "$all" },

    // Match the seen value
    { "$project": {
        "all": 1,
        "one": 1,
        "two": 1,
        "seen": {
            "$eq": [ "$all", "$two" ]
        }    
    }},

    // Filter the seen value
    { "$match": { "seen": false } },

    // Group back again 
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "one": { "$first": "$one" },
        "two": { "$first": "$two },
        "three": { "$first": "$three" }
    }}
])
```

Or modify the map reduce above at the mapper since we are really only artificially producing the array:

```js
    function () {
        this.eqtcorp.forEach(doc) {
            emit( this.company, doc );
        });
    }
```

Which still makes sense to split this up when combining keys

---

Of course if there is no actual aggregation going on between documents and you basic intent is to just get the last three values of the array in each document, then the clear approach is to "sort" them as documents are updated and items are added to the array. So your approach to add new items becomes:

```js
db.collection.update(
    { _id: document_id },
    {
        "$push": {
            "eqtcorp": { 
                "$each": [ { new document }, { optionally more} ],
                "$sort": { "DATE": 1 }
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Prior to MongoDB 2.6 this also requires a **`$slice`** modifier which would basically impose an upper limit on the number of items in the array but this is no longer required. With earlier versions you might have to supply an upper limit value to this, such as `500` or other number larger than your expected results unless you actually wanted to "prune" results in which case set your limits.

The point being here that without any aggregation going on then when you just want the last three values of that array from a document then you just do this with projection and the [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) operator that is available there:

```js
db.collection.find({},{ "eqtcorp": { "$slice": -3 } })
```

As the array items in the document are already sorted you just get the last three values, and your done.

---

So really, while you can process your existing document using mapReduce, unless you really want to aggregate results it is a much slower process. Changing the data to be arrays and maintaining the sort order will immediately get you the results you want with a very simple query that is fast.

Even if your intention is aggregation, then the options available to you when using arrays are much wider and it is generally easier to do more complex things.

Answer (score 1):

if the subdocument "eqtcorp" is stored as array as mentioned below

```
    {
        "name" : "306113", // assigned it to a node to create an array
        "DATE" : "2014-05-05 16:43:00.000",
        "subsection_name" : "CORPORATE NEWS",
        "time" : "16:43"
    }
```

**To update a single document**

```
db.collection_name.update(
         { company : "500010"}, 
         { $push : {
            eqtcorp : {
            $each: [ ],
            $sort : { "DATE" : -1},
            $slice : 3
        }
    }
})
```

**To update all the documents**

```
    db.collection_name.update(
    {}, // query all documents
    {
    $push : {
            eqtcorp : {
                $each: [ ],
                $sort : { "DATE" : -1},
                $slice : 3
            }
        }
    }, 
    false, 
    true // update multiple documents
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest Query would be Sort the subdocument array based on date ,and Use Slice operator to get required data via projection

```
db.collection_name.find({"company": "500010"},{ "eqtcorp": { "$slice": -3 } }).sort({"eqtcorp.DATE":-1})
```